# Android writing a csv file, Uri.fromFile return NullPointerException

Tags: android, csv, file, nullpointerexception, uri

I am trying to write a collection into a CSV file, but I am getting a `NullPointerException` at my file.
The activity also should ask for permission but that seemed to work.
I am also able to export a CSV file in a different way to other apps.

Sorry if this post is a bit confusing, looking forward to any type of help.
Thanks in advance

generateCSV in my Activity

```
public void generateCsv(MenuItem item) {

        csvGenerator = new CSVGenerator(getString(R.string.app_name),getString(R.string.app_name));
        csvGenerator.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

        csvGenerator.setSubtitle("Projekt");
        csvGenerator.addKeyValue("Name","PName");
        csvGenerator.addKeyValue("Decription","PDesc");

        csvGenerator.addNewLine();


        String[] exceptionUser = {"status"};
        csvGenerator.addTable("Projekt Data", projektList,exceptionUser);

        Uri uri = csvGenerator.generate();

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,R.string.app_name);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        sendIntent.setType("text/csv");
        startActivity(sendIntent);

    }
```

generate in my csvGenerator

```
public Uri generate(){
        Log.d("DATA-content",content);
        File file = fileHelper.storeFile(content);
        Uri uri  =   Uri.fromFile(file);

        clearContent();
        return uri;
    }
```

And my storeFile

```
 public File storeFile(String content){
        File file   = null;
        File root   = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (root.canWrite()){
            File dir    =   new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/"+getDirName());
            dir.mkdirs();
            file   =   new File(dir, getFileName()+".csv");
            FileOutputStream out   =   null;
            Log.d("CSV-FILE",dir.getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                out.write(content.getBytes());
                out.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("CSV-ERROR",e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("CSV-ERROR",e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return file;
    }
```

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.za, PID: 31946
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(SupportMenuInflater.java:271)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:154)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:330)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1257)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(SupportMenuInflater.java:267)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:154) 
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985) 
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128) 
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:330) 
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1257) 
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3265) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: file
        at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:473)
        at com.example.za.csv.CSVGenerator.generate(CSVGenerator.java:157)
        at com.example.za.projekt.ProjektActivity.generateCsv(ProjektActivity.java:249)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(SupportMenuInflater.java:267) 
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:154) 
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985) 
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128) 
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:330) 
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1257) 
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3265) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Comment: Add `if (file==null) return;` before you call Uri.fromFile(); Display a Toast too to inform the user about the null. And realize that null is returned by storeFile if canWrite is false;

Comment: `dir.mkdirs();` Only call mkdirs() if the directory does not exist yet. And if you call it then check the return value. And if the return value is false then stop and display a toast to inform the user. I bet that the directory is not created to begin with.

Comment: thx but how can i fix that canWrite is false?

Comment: That depends on the Android version of used device. And you should start telling what you already did to obtain a write permission. Further: Even if you can write you return the File instance allways. Even if you have one of those exceptions. You should return null if the file cannot be written. The caller should know if all went ok.